# searchsorted - global name "x" is not defined

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to use the `numpy` method called `searchsorted` but i can not make it work.

This is the code:

```
class Object(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    QMainWindow.__init(self)

    self.figure_canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure())
    self.axes = self.figure_canvas.add_subplot(111)

    x = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.01)
    y = np.sin(2*np.pi*x) + 0.5*np.random.randn(len(x))
    self.axes.plot(x, y, "-", picker = 5)
    self.axes.set_ylim(-2, 2)

  def onselect(xmin, xmax):
    indmin, indmax = np.searchsorted(x, (xmin, xmax)
```

and, when i try to build this code, i get an error that says:

`NameError: global name 'x' is not defined`

What is the problem? i defined the x that i want to use, but it says that it is not.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: There is a missing `)`.

Comment: The variable x is just declared in __init__ funtion but not visible to onselect()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only define the local variable `x` within the scope of your `__init__()` function, so it can't be accessed outside of this scope.

If instead you set `x` to be an instance attribute using `self.x` you will be able to access it in your `onselect()` class method, again via `self.x`:

```
class Object(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    QMainWindow.__init(self)

    self.figure_canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure())
    self.axes = self.figure_canvas.add_subplot(111)

    self.x = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.01)
    y = np.sin(2*np.pi*x) + 0.5*np.random.randn(len(x))
    self.axes.plot(x, y, "-", picker = 5)
    self.axes.set_ylim(-2, 2)

  def onselect(self, xmin, xmax):
    indmin, indmax = np.searchsorted(self.x, (xmin, xmax)
```

Comment: Pedantically, `x` is an instance attribute, not a class attribute here.

Comment: I tried this. When i write `self.x`, i have to put it like this in the `y`variable too and in `self.axes.plot()` . But in this time, i get the error: `Name Error: global ´self´ is not defined`

Comment: @PabloFlores ensure that `onselect()` is a class method by defining it within your class and passing it the `self` argument

Comment: I think that is what i was missing. So to call the `onselect` method, do i have to write: self.onselect(self) in the `__init__` method ?

Comment: You can just call it with `self.onselect(xmin, xmax)` - you don't need to pass the `self` argument explicitly

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers and helping me. But i have to bother you with one more thing. If i write `self.onselect(xmin, xmax)` i get: `NameError: global name "xmin" is not defined`. And i suppose that i will get the same with `xmax`

Comment: Agreed - you need to pass in values for `xmin` and `xmax`! Unfortunately I don't know what they are or represent....

Comment: i'm trying to do this: http://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/span_selector.html , but with a class like the code above.

Answer (score 2):

You defined an `x` in your `__init__` method.  Your `onselect` has no `x` defined

If you want to use that `x` in other methods of that instance, you can do

```
self.x = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.01) # this is in __init__
```

Then in `onselect` you can reference it by using `self.x`

Answer (score 1):

In onselect() funtion there ir no x value declared

Try this:

```
def __init__(self):
  ...
  self.x = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.01)

def onselect(xmin, xmax):
  indmin, indmax = np.searchsorted(self.x, (xmin, xmax)
```